# ScrollViews and FlatList doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, react-native

I receive this error in my app:

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
```

I have and index.js

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
   //...
{selected === 1 && <Component1 />}
{ selected === 2 && <Component2 />}
  </ScrollView>
```

Now inside my Component2 I have

```
<View>
 //....
<CustomFlatList data={dataPermission()}
</View>
```

I use this dataPermission to popolute "data"

and at the end in my CustomFlatList I use the FlatList

```
const renderItem = () => {
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.row]}>
  //....
</TouchableOpacity>
 }


if (data.length == 0) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        //....
      </View>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList data={data} renderItem={renderItem} />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Now my problem is that I have used in the index.js a ScrollView with inside a FlatList and I suppose that is the problem.

In your opinion how can I do to fix this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message is straight forward: You should never nest a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView`. This is because the parent `scroll action dominates the child scroll action`.

This problem is easy to resolve. Replace the parent `ScrollView` with a normal `View`. The `FlatList` already supports scrolling. If you have multiple sections (i.e. different data sets), then you might want to use a [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist).

**Remark:**
You can usually achieve visually the same with a `ScrollView` as you could do with a `FlatList` BUT

> ScrollView renders all its react child components at once, but this has a performance downside.

Thus, it is advised to use a `FlatList` whenever one want to render data inside a scrollable container.